# TestLink build Execution status always "Not Run" in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testlink

I am working on integration of Jenkins, Test Link and Robot framework integration.

Robot scripts are stored in Jenkins.

My build seems to run fine in Jenkins, but the problems are after:

1. The build indicates "Not Run" as execution state.
2. The tests status is not updated in TestLink.

TestLink version: 1.9.14
TestLink Plugin: 3.12

Could any one help me here?

Comment: What do you mean by "stored in jenkins"? Jenkins isn't a storage system.

Comment: All robot framework scripts are placed in Jenkins machine.

Comment: What type of job is this? Freestyle? Matrix? I don't see anything from a quick look at the TestLink plugin that sets the build status to "not run".

Comment: Its a Freestyle Project

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate the result is not getting updated in TestLink even after successful build. Build is automatically created in TestLink

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Use a simple test case name. As simple as possible.

Tried to use something like `F01T01AUTO`. Same result as above. Changed to `Testcase1` and works like a charm!